# Geometric intuition of commutation of submanifolds of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, matrices

This is a possibly "out there" question so I apologize if it doesn't seem well defined.

Let's say I have two submanifolds $X$ and $Y$ of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ of dimension $m<n^2$. If locally $X$ is given in coordinates by a matrix $A$ of full rank and the same for $Y$ with matrix $B$, then is there any nice geometric way of thinking about $AB-BA$ as a new submanifold? What conditions on $X$ and $Y$ would I need to even allow for this concept to make sense (if any)?

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand the question: what do you mean by $X$ locally given in coordinates by $A$?